# Model panel data with ONLY time-invariant variables

Tags: modeling, econometrics, panel-data, invariance

I have a large dataset containing computers and their specifications. I collected 20 different prices over a period of 20 weeks for each computer.
Now I want to build a model with the price as a dependent variable, and the product specifications as independent variables.

I would like to find out the best method to do this. All my independent variables are time-invariant for one specific computer, so I know a fixed effect model is probably not an option. But I have also read that pooled OLS and random effects models can give biased and inconsistent results, so I am a little confused here...

Many thanks!

Comment: You can try a Hausman test to decide if a FE or a RE model is appropriate.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Thanks for your reply. At this moment I don't think FE is going to work for me, since FE only *controls* for the time-invariant variables, but I wish to estimate the *effects* of the time-invariant variables. So I'm wondering whether the Hausman-test could tell me whether the estimates of RE are biased or not? Or does a test like that simply not exist?

Comment: That's exactly what the test will tell you. Also, some people have tried to model the FE as an outcome of the time invariant regressors, but that it's not quite right since it is an estimated quantity.